# Develop Mobile Theme in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have made a wordpress theme of a site. I used Starker Theme for the wordpress theme development. Now I want to make my site Mobile Friendly. Is there any solution to make few changes or using some plugins for this purpose? I have tried wptouch, WordPress Mobile Pack and MobilePress but they are not working. I have checked my output on the http://mobiletest.me, but this is not displaying the accurate mobile Output (Output is same as on my PC Browser). Either there is problem in this testing site or plugin? All this make me confused.

Please let me know any other solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be checking your site properly. Make sure you have this line of code in your html head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Without that line of code, your device will display the page the same as the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of MobileTest.me, just want to clarify a few things.
As you have correctly noticed, mobiletest.me uses your PC browser's engine to render the website you want to test. This is by design as it was created as a tool to test responsive web design. The mobile devices are provided as an indicator of common smartphone resolutions.

If what you want is to send a different theme to desktop browsers and a different one to mobile devices then you probably need a wordpress plugin such as [mobile detector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mobile-detector/). The problem with this approach is that if the plugin fails to determine the device browser correctly, it will probably send the PC version to a mobile device.

The other approach is [responsive design](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-responsive-web-design) which sends different CSS based on the resolution of a device and does not rely on browser detection. If you decide to go the responsive way you may find [this post](http://demianlabs.com/lab/post/how-to-test-your-mobile-web-site-or-app-across-multiple-devices/) useful where you can check some examples of how mobiletest.me can be used to check responsive web designs (images are clickable).